# How can I use beautiful soup on multiple pages at the same time?

Tags: beautifulsoup, request

Im using beautiful soup to scrape a website. it has pages of data that i want to sum together. However, doing it page by page with beautiful soup takes about 2 seconds per page, and so it takes almost a day to do the thousands of pages i want. A lot of the time is just spent waiting for the url request, so i think i could do this by seperating the task and running a hundred python scripts at once. But is there a way to do that within one python script?

Comment: threading, multiprocessing

Answer (score 1):

You could run multiple threads, using multithreading.Pool, but probably not hundreds unless you have a supercomputer. The number of logical processors on the machine running your code is probably the optimal number of threads to use.
However, there are two things to consider:

1. The lag when waiting for the url request is caused by a networking bottleneck, not slow code in your program. More threads might not actually improve the overall speed, because **more threads doesn't give you a faster internet connection.** Maybe two or three threads would be faster than one, but there is a limit at which point your internet speed becomes the weak link for speed.
2. If the server you're scraping from sees you sending several requests per second, **you may be blacklisted for causing too much load.** It's usually good practice when scraping to be courteous to the server you're downloading from, that is, it's a bad idea to spam the server with multiple requests in quick succession.